# Reading Input from Text Box to Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, code-behind

I have here a text box in ASP.NET Webform format

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Year_BuiltTextBox" CssClass="datepicker" 
      placeholder="Click to open calendar" runat="server" 
      Text='<%# Bind("DateBuilt","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' />
```

I want to read the input of the user from the text-box and change the format of the date using C# as the code behind.

e.g. From input of 2005 it will become 1/1/2005.

Thank you.

Comment: So show what you have already tried.

Comment: This is "Step 1" in any WebForms user input tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);`  Uses year entered by user, Jan as the month and 1 as the day.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a lost cause, but I will attempt anyways.

You have 2 options, the easy post-back way, and the hard ajax way.

The easy way:
All you need to do is on *some* event look at the value in the text box.

```
string inputValue = Year_BuiltTextBox.Text;
DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(inputValue.Text), 1, 1);
Year_BuiltTextBox.Text = inputDate.ToString();
```

You can use other forms of `ToString()` to suit your needs.

The hard(er) way:
Personaly, I have no idea how to use this, but I have co-workers who say this is a lifesaver. Ajax has a `Calendar Extender` that you can attach to your text box that allows the user to input a date directly (they can also type in the field). An example can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx). If you want to go this route, learn how to impliment ajax on your page. A resource for this can be found [here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/11/ajax-calendarextender-how-to-use.html) (please note the script manager).